# How to relate the <decision> and <state> in JPDL in JBPM4 to BPMN2.0 in JBPM7?

Tags: jbpm, bpmn

I have a simple 3 steps process definition which i have defined in JPDL from JBPM4.3, and i will like to remodel using BPMN2 in JBPM7 but i have problem trying to do so. For example, i have a JPDL that looks like this (i simplified it as the actual one is quite complex):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<process key="PROCESS_EXTERNAL_RESPONSE" name="PROCESS_EXTERNAL_RESPONSE" xmlns="http://jbpm.org/4.2/jpdl">
    <start g="66,20,48,48">
        <transition to="SEND_AND_WAIT"/>
    </start>
    <state g="662,145,80,40" name="SEND_AND_WAIT" continue="async" class="com.examples.SendAndWaitStateHandler">
        <transition g="-79,-18" name="Completed" to="PROCESS_RESPONSE"/>
        <transition g="-85,-25" name="Error" to="ERROR_AND_ABORT" />
    </state>
    <decision g="673,346,80,40" name="PROCESS_RESPONSE" continue="async">
        <handler class="com.examples.ProcessResponseStateHandler">
        </handler>
        <transition g="-79,-18" name="Completed" to="end"/>
        <transition g="-79,-18" name="Error" to="ERROR_AND_ABORT"/>
    </decision>
    <state g="501,345,92,52" name="ERROR_AND_ABORT" class="com.examples.AbortStateHandler" continue="async">
        <transition g="-45,-18" name="Retry" to="SEND_AND_WAIT"/>
        <transition g="-45,-18" name="Abort" to="end"/>
    </state>
    <end g="391,494,48,48" name="end"/> 
</process>
```

Basically, when the process starts, it creates a request and send to an external system. Then, it goes into a WAIT state to wait for the response. Once it got the response, it processes the response and make a decision if it should proceed or error out. In event of error, the process will transition to the "ERROR AND ABORT" wait state where the user or timer can send a signal "retry" from the application to transition to the "SEND_AND_WAIT" state again.How do i model this using BPMN2.0 in JBPM7?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

from my understanding, it may look like this... please clarify whether this helps or not or put the comment if this is not what you expect

Comment: Can you share the bpmn xml file for this? Thank you.